# How to create a hit counter module in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, counter

How to create a hit counter module in joomla 2.5

Comment: What have you tried so far? In all probability, Joomla already has a hit counter module. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension to create hit counter

[Module Hit Counter](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/20925)

Answer (score 1):

In production Joomla will have cache enabled, and this makes it necessary to handle the hit counting with javascript.

Since we accept this limitation, maybe it's best to use a dedicated server such as piwik, that beyond counting hits will also allow you to study trends, analyse referrals, navigation paths,  time on site etc.